# How do you transfer a blood curse?

Tags: magic, blood

The curse is made into a tea using the ashes of war, the blood of fallen soldiers, and the tears of their widows and then given to the victim to drink. Since the curse is in the victim's body and made from blood, how could it be deflected or transferred onto someone else?

Comment: these type of questions arent really liked because they are opinion based/have no defined answer

Comment: yeah, it is the matter of u magical system hence story/work-based and general handwavium and smart face solves it

Answer (score 2):

## Blood donations

A human body usually has around a gallon of blood (UK gallons at least). A donation of blood usually involved extracting a pound of blood. And I've finally gone full 'merican by not using metric measurements in an answer.

You can usually donate blood 2 to 4 times a year, depensong on the laws of where you live. And each blood bag helps up to four people. In this manner you can transfer part of your curse to random strangers.

It is a temporary curse anyway. Red blood cells do not live long, they last for less than a year. As for white cells, each kind has its own life time, but spans between 20 and 115 days are common.